# How to get modified files when I pull using NetBeans?

Tags: git, netbeans, pull, git-pull

I get this kind of message when i am trying to pull from NetBeans 7.2:

> ==[IDE]== 05-nov-2012 14:52:04 Pulling...
>
> git pull ssh://git@ip/home/git/project/ +refs/heads/Dev_Nov_1:refs/remotes/origin/Dev_Nov_1
>
> Branch  : origin/Dev_Nov_1
>
> Old Id : xxxx
>
> New Id : xxxy
>
> Result : FAST_FORWARD
>
> Merge Result: Fast-forward
>
> Merge of HEAD with origin/Dev_Nov_1:
>
> Commit Log
>
> revision   : xxxx
>
> author     : cesar
>
> date       : 05-nov-2012 14:51:13
>
> summary    : test commit
>
> ==[IDE]== 05-nov-2012 14:52:38 Pulling... finished.

And I would like to get also the list of modified files .

I know that using `git log --stat` I can get it, but does anyone know how to do this using Netbeans?

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of files changed:

- Right click on the project in the project browser and select Git->Show History from the menu
- Select the search button - this will give you a summary of the commits
- Select a commit and the files changed are show
- Select the diff tab and a file is you want to see the changes to the files

Comment: Yep, I know that way. That are four manual steps to get to some information that would have been displayed on the console already. Currently I'm trying to get used to Aptana, which has a nice Git UI build in…